# Return from inside an observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm think fundamentally i'm doing something wrong. I'm trying to find a single entity by pulling it from filtered list, if there isn't an entity there I need to create one.

I feel like this function is wrong because I should be returning an observable but instead returning nothing

```
getOrCreateNew(receiverId: number) : Observable<Conversation> {
    var userId = this.identity.userInfo.id;

    //TODO: you should be using an expression here, and having a builder for generating your
    //filters in case you want to switch them in the future
    var employerFilter = new PropertyFilterNode("EmployerUserId", FilterCondition.Equal, receiverId.toString());
    var employeeFilter = new PropertyFilterNode("EmployeeUserId", FilterCondition.Equal, userId.toString());
    let conversationFilter = new BinaryFilterNode(employerFilter, employeeFilter, Combiner.Or);

    this.getList(conversationFilter).subscribe(entities => {
        if (entities == null || entities.length == 0) {
            let conversation: Conversation;
            conversation.employerUserId = receiverId;
            conversation.employeeUserId = userId;
            return this.create(conversation);
        }
        else {
            let entity = entities[0];
            return Observable.of(entity); //.Return(entity)
        }
    });

    return null;
}
```

How can I return an observable which is return from inside subscribe?

Comment: how is `getOrCreateNew` used? It seems to return `null` but is typed as returning an observable. Also, you have type annotations in several places that may mask errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `getList` subscription works suggests that it is supposed to be `mergeMap` or `switchMap` (considering that `create` returns an observable as well):

```
return this.getList(conversationFilter).mergeMap(entities => {
    if (entities == null || entities.length == 0) {
        let conversation: Conversation;
        conversation.employerUserId = receiverId;
        conversation.employeeUserId = userId;
        return this.create(conversation);
    }
    else {
        let entity = entities[0];
        return Observable.of(entity); //.Return(entity)
    }
});
```

In this case an observable that is returned from `getOrCreateNew` should be subscribed in order to emit values because it isn't subscribed internally.

Answer (score 1):

Place the `return` before `this.getList` also :

```
return this.getList(conversationFilter).subscribe(entities => {
```

Comment: Get list returns a Observable<Array<Conversation>> i need to use that value to then conditionally return the observable inside I need it to return Observable<Conversation>

Comment: then you should use `mergeMap` or `flatMap` instead of subscribe.